# How to reduce the redundant rows in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

```
#Given a dataframe

#report1                             match      report2
#1 Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf      87.5      Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf
#2 Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf      93.33     Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf
#3 Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf      87.5      Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf
#4 Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf      93.33     Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf
#5 Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf      93.33     Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf
#6 Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf      93.33     Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf
```

How do remove redundant rows from this dataframe? Where row 1 is a duplicate of row 3, as is row 2 and row 5, row 4 and row 6.  I created the following code to delete the referenced line within the dataframe where a match occurs but I'm not getting the right results.  Please advise, thank you.

````
     rpt1=df$report1
    rpt2=df$report2
    match =df$match

    for (j in 1:length(rpt1)){
    for (k in 1:length(rpt1)){
     if ((rpt1[j] == rpt2[k]) && (rpt1[k] == rpt2[j])){
     df = df[-j, ]
      }
    next
    }
    } 
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can try an approach using a key dataframe based on the unique values of both report variables an then smartly build an id that allows removing duplicated cases. Here the code in two versions:

```
#Code
Keys <- data.frame(v1=c(unique(df$report1),unique(df$report2)))
#Assign value
Keys$id <- 1:nrow(Keys)
#Match
df$i1 <- Keys[match(df$report1,Keys$v1),"id"]
df$i2 <- Keys[match(df$report2,Keys$v1),"id"]
df$i3 <- apply(df[,c('i1','i2')],1,function(x) paste0(sort(x),collapse = ''))
#Remove duplicates 1
df1 <- df[!duplicated(df$i3),]
df1 <- df1[,c(1:3)]
#Remove duplicates 2
df2 <- df[!duplicated(df$i3,fromLast = T),]
df2 <- df2[,c(1:3)]
```

Outputs:

```
df1
                        report1 match                       report2
1 Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf 87.50 Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf
2 Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf 93.33 Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf
4 Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf 93.33 Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf

df2
                        report1 match                       report2
3 Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf 87.50 Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf
5 Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf 93.33 Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf
6 Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf 93.33 Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(report1 = c("Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf", "Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf", 
"Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf", "Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf", 
"Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf", "Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf"
), match = c(87.5, 93.33, 87.5, 93.33, 93.33, 93.33), report2 = c("Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf", 
"Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf", "Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf", 
"Document_2.pdf&Document_3.pdf", "Document_1.pdf&Document_2.pdf", 
"Document_1.pdf&Document_3.pdf")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: I think your data as you shared must be a big dataset, you can format it to remove the duplicated rows as in this post and then send to the loop!